# How to save to two tables from one form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a regular form for User information which starts like so:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    ...
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => "submit_button" if @user.last_step? %>
<% end %>
```

I also have some non User fields in the form.  Here's an example:

```
<%= f.label "When is your birthday?" %>
<%= select_tag "month" %>
<%= select_tag "day" %>
<%= select_tag "year" %>
```

How would I save this to a different table than User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a model other than User, you should probably use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). The alternative is to just do the work in your `create` action of your `UsersController`, ie:

```
def create
  @user = User.create params[:user]
  @foo = Foo.find params[:foo_id]
  @foo.date = Date.new(params[:foo_year], params[:foo_month], params[:foo_day])
  ...
end
```